# Firebase - Reducing Costs by moving historical data from Realtime DB to Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

We are using Realtime DB for syncing data in realtime to client devices, and that is resulting in a large bill from Firebase.

Since Firestore charges less for storage and read/writes are expensive, can I reduce my costs by moving data to Firestore, making my realtime DB lighter and hence reducing the storage costs there?

The app has low number of writes, it is mostly a read-intensive application.

Help appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you still want to do on the historical data. If you want to only keep it around for historical reference, I'd actually recommend keeping in in BigQuery, which has much better query capabilities.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense, but I want to keep it available in case users request it.

Comment: In that case any cloud accessible database would be fine I guess, so pick whatever is cheapest (since that seems to be your primary motivator). If you pick Firestore, be sure to pick a scheme that puts a reasonable chunk of data in each document, as otherwise the read costs will still add up.